# How can I get VMWare to use the same IP as the host?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, vmware-player

I am running RHEL 6 on my Win-XP using VMware.

On VMware it has the local IP. I want it to be same as that of XP.

i.e. 123.237.115.199 on both. (This is dynamic IP but I want that the dynamic IP on both should be same, whatever it is)

How can I do it?

Here are all the info.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two different devices on the same network cannot have the same IP address. How would you expect the packets to get to the right device?

Comment: They're most likely not on the same network. I'll bet that "the IP address" of the Windows machine is in fact the IP address of its Ethernet adapter, or Wifi - certainly a physical network. The RHEL adapter is virtual, and therefore not on the physical network. It does leave you with a big question, how would you _reach_ that RHEL address? While it's somewhat possible to reuse addresses on different networks, that does mean that routing between them becomes practically impossible.

Comment: I believe you'd have to use a NAT operating mode for your virtual nic. Explore the network types in your VMs config in VMware.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They can't use the same ip address unless NAT is turned on. If NAT is enabled, the host's IP is like a router to the VM. If bridged mode is enabled, the VM gets a new address from your current router, as if it's a physical computer